# Using generics in closure callers

Tags: swift, generics, closures, overloading

I have 2 overloaded functions and I'm trying to call them using their signature in caller using generic. For example:

```
func sum(_ i: Int, _ s: Int){
print("sum \(i+s)")
}

func sum(_ i: String, _ s: Int){
var res: String="";
for _ in 1...s{
    res += i
}
print("Repeat \(res)")
}

func sumCaller<T>(_ f: T){
print(type(of: f)) // compiler prints the value is function (Int,Int)->Void !!!
}

sumCaller(sum as (Int, Int)->Void)
```

Everything fine here. But when I'm trying to call `f` in `sumCaller` like this

```
func sumCaller<T>(_ f: T){
print(type(of: f)) //compiler prints the value is function (Int,Int)->Void !!!
f(1,3)
}
```

compiler throwing error:

`error: testing.playground:68:5: error: cannot call value of non-function type 'T' f(1,3)`

But it's still the same function I pass as `sumCaller` argument. Please, can someone explain me my mistake?

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to achieve. Can you explain your expected result?

Comment: I'm trying to understand why compiler trowing error that it's not a function but printing that it is. Further, I'd like to call different closures via different signatures

Comment: At compile time the compiler has no idea what kind of type T is. And it cannot assume it's a function. Only at runtime the program itself can see that the T you are passing is indeed a function. But the way you wrote your code there is nothing stopping you calling `sumCaller` with any other type instead of a function.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your goal is but the bellow code "does something". Hope it's what you're looking for:

```
func sum(_ i: Int, _ s: Int){
    print("sum \(i+s)")
}

func sum(_ i: String, _ s: Int){
    var res: String="";
    for _ in 1...s{
        res += i
    }
    print("Repeat \(res)")
}

func sumCaller<A, B>(_ f: (A, B) -> Void, a: A, b: B) {
    print(type(of: f)) // compiler prints the value is function (Int,Int)->Void !!!
    f(a, b)
}

sumCaller(sum, a: 2, b: 3)
sumCaller(sum, a: "Test", b: 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

When you're using a generic function, `T` is a placeholder type name instead of an actual type name, as you already know.  A placeholder could be of any type including `String`, `Dictionary`, `Int`, etc.  Only when the function is called, the actual type is inserted in place of `T`.  This process of replacing the generic type with an actual type is called specializing or resolving the generic.  In order for the generic to be resolved, the compiler demands that there is no ambiguity as to what this `T` is, otherwise it will throw an error, which is what's happening here.

When you look at this code:

```swift
func sumCaller<T>(_ f: T){
   print(type(of: f)) //compiler prints the value is function (Int,Int)->Void !!!
   f(1,3)
}
```

there is no chance for this function to be called and have `T` substituted with an actual type, which means, `T` is still a placeholder and could be of any type.  For example, `f` could be of `String` type, which means `f(1,3)` equates to `String(1,3)`, which doesn't make sense.  The compiler is letting you know that there is still ambiguity as to what `T` could be.

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be easiest to understand this if you just forget about T and the generic and just think about what the compiler knows vs. what is true at runtime.

Consider first just this code:

```
func myFunc(_ : Int, _ : Int) { print("it worked") }
let f : Any = myFunc
print(type(of: f)) // (Int, Int) -> ()
```

That code compiles and runs and, as my comment indicates, prints `(Int, Int) -> ()`. But that is a *runtime* print. When the app *runs*, the runtime looks at what `f` *really* is and prints that out.

But long before the code runs, it must *compile*. The compiler knows only how things are typed *externally*. So as far as the compiler is concerned, `f` is an Any and that's all it is. *You* know that `f` is a function, but the compiler does not know that!

So, now we'll add a line to our code, and it won't compile any more:

```
func myFunc(_ : Int, _ : Int) { print("it worked") }
let f : Any = myFunc
print(type(of: f))
f(1,2) // cannot call value of non-function type 'Any'
```

Do you see? The compiler has no idea there is a function *inside* `f`. It sees only `f`, which is an Any. It is not until *runtime* that `f` will have a genuine value that can be examined.

We can solve the problem by *forcing* the compiler to *believe* that this will turn out to be a function at runtime:

```
func myFunc(_ : Int, _ : Int) { print("it worked") }
let f : Any = myFunc
print(type(of: f)) // (Int, Int) -> ()
(f as! (Int,Int) -> ())(1,2) // it worked
```

That compile compiles *and* runs *and* the function is successfully called, as we know because it prints out `"it worked"`.

What happened? Our use of `as!` (a forced *cast*) tells the compiler to throw away its own beliefs and just accept blindly our assertion that when the app runs, `f` will turn out to be a function. So the compiler lets us pretend that that is true, and takes away its objection and lets us run the code. We told the truth, so our code runs successfully too.

But if we had lied — if `f` were some other sort of thing — then the compiler would still not object, but our app would *crash* at the moment of the `as!` cast.

```
func myFunc(_ : Int, _ : Int) { print("it worked") }
let f : Any = 1
print(type(of: f)) // (Int, Int) -> ()
(f as! (Int,Int) -> ())(1,2) // crash
```